# Array type int[] is not assignable

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I am implementing an ADT Stack using an array.  I want to doubling the size of the array when the stack is full.

```cpp
const int MAX_SIZE = 6 // max size of array stack
template<class ItemType>
class ArrayStack: public StackInterface<ItemType>{
private:
    ItemType items[MAX_SIZE]; // Array of stack items
    int top; // index of top
    int itemCount; // Amount of items in stack
    int maxsize;
```

This is my push method:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayStack<ItemType>::push(const ItemType& newEntry){
    if(itemCount == maxsize){ // resize array
        cout << "resizing an array..." << endl; // just for testing
        ItemType* oldArray = items; // old array to be deleted
        ItemType* newItems = new ItemType[2*maxsize];

        for(int i=0; i<maxsize; i++){
            newItems[i] = oldArray[i]; // copying all array items
        }
        delete[] oldArray; // deallocate
        maxsize = maxsize * 2; // doubling max size
        items = newItems; <- I'm getting error from this code
    } // end if

    // Stack is not full
    top++;
    items[top] = newEntry;
    itemCount++;
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to double the size of the array:

```
error: array type 'int [6]' is not assignable
items = newItems;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are managing the dynamic array manually instead of using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?  Or even, why you are not using [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) to begin with?

Comment: Actually i'm studying to "Data Abstraction and Problem Solving with C++" and i'm in chapter 7, they created array stack class like this and in the "doubling an array when stack becomes full" section they did double an array as i indicated in the code

Comment: You can't change the size of a *fixed* array, you can only allocate a new *dynamic* array and maintain a **pointer** to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i definitely agree with you, that's why i asked this question in here because it didn't make sense when i see the answer of question in the book

Comment: If the book shows a pointer being assigned to an array, then the book is wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is what book shows `ItemType* oldArray = items; items = new ItemType[maxsize*2]  for(i 0 to itemcount i++) items[i] = oldArray[i]`  first i tried this solution after it didn't work i tried to assign an array to pointer

Comment: That part of the code is fine. I was referring to the actual declaration of the `items` member in the class.  If the book is declared `items` as an `ItemType[]` array and not as an `ItemType* pointer, then the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemType items[MAX_SIZE];` is a fixed array.  You can't resize it, you can't reallocate it, and you certainly can't assign an `ItemType*` pointer to it.

For what you are attempting to do, `items` needs to be an `ItemType*` pointer instead of an `ItemType[]` array:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
class ArrayStack: public StackInterface<ItemType>{
private:
    ItemType *items; // Array of stack items
    ...
};
```

Don't forget to initialize `items` in your constructor(s), and call `delete[] items;` in the destructor, and also implement proper copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).